# Continuous android location background from Android OS 8 or higher

Tags: android, service, background, gps, location

I am trying to fetch user **exact location** by running a **location service** in **background** but **onLocationChanged** event only triggers when app is in **foreground**. As soon as app goes **background or killed** my location services doesn't trigger onLocationChanged event from service due to which I am unable to get user exact location.

I am using **FusedLocationProviderClient API** in my location service. As per https://developer.android.com/training/location/background there are some limitation on location background. Where in document it was saying itself:

> If background location access is essential for your app, keep in mind that Android preserves device battery life by setting *background location limits* on devices that run *Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher*. On these versions of Android, **if your app is running in the background, it can receive location updates only a few times each hour**.

Please help me to achieve my functionality. Any guideline / help / code sample / link / hint would be great appreciate.

Comment: Use [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) to continuously fetch location even when app is in background

Answer (score 1):

Start a foreground service in your app by calling startForegroundService(). When such a foreground service is active, it appears as an ongoing notification in the notification area.

Comment: I already doing the same but the OEM brands like Oppo, Vivo, Samsung, Mi in such devices location service is not triggering onLocationChanged event. Only when app is in foreground it works and gives me accurate GPS data. But not in background or when user presses the device power button and switch off the screen

Comment: @Arno den Hond using foreground service it works. I am making silly mistake while starting foreground services.